# show a dialogfragment using notification

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have set up a notification like this in my `.MainActivity` class:

```
 Intent downloadUpdateIntent = new Intent(mContext, updateAppDialogFragment.class);
            PendingIntent downloadAppPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,0,downloadUpdateIntent,0);


    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Update Available")
            .setContentText("A new version of this app is available.")
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .addAction(0,"Update",downloadAppPendingIntent);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(mContext.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

What i need is to, when i click on `update` button, it should show `updateAppDialogFragment` to show an updating progress. When i generally use this class, i need to make such a call `updateAppDialogFragment.newInstance()`. But here, I cant understand how to accomplish this. Anyone to help?

I have very basic knowledge about intent. Actually, what i need to know is to use the intent to call a method.